# Printf adding digit

Tags: c, console, printf

I have a small program:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    float num1;
    float num2;

    num1 = 21.2;
    num2 = 13.6;

    double sum;

    sum = num1 + num2;

    printf("The sum of two numbers is %3.5f. \n", sum);


    return 0;
}
```

When this prints to the console, this is what I get:

The sum of two numbers is `34.800003`

Why am I getting that 3 at the end of the decimal? Trying to understand `Printf`, but this is mysterious to me....

Comment: Read "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @SecurityMatt The problem is that the precision for `printf` is specified as five digits.

Comment: Are you sure about that output? http://ideone.com/VRj497

Comment: Can't repro, my `printf` respects the precision. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @DanielFischer increate the precision from `.5` to `.15` or higher and you will see. It may be platform dependent.

Comment: @SecurityMatt For `printf`, the `l` length modifier id ignored for floating point numbers, it's only the `scanf` family where that matters. It might be that the OP didn't copy and accidentally typed one 0 too many. But I'm a bit naive and assume the best. If there are actually only five digits after the decimal (four zeros), then the usual floating point advice of course applies.

Answer (score 0):

Do the addition using double precision:

```
sum = num1;
sum += num2;
```

or apply some casting:

```
sum = (double) num1 + (double) num2;
```

Comment: The problem is that more digits after the decimal are printed than specified, the format is `%3.5f`.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the precision of numbers. If you are interested in the details, I recommend check out [Wikipedia on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). The format in which they are stored is only accurate to a certain degress.

For higher accuracy use the `double` type:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    double num1;
    double num2;

    num1 = 21.2;
    num2 = 13.6;

    double sum;

    sum = num1 + num2;

    printf("The sum of two numbers is %3.5f. \n", sum);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every thing in c is done in bit just print the hexadecimal value of num1and num2. What u are missing is 0.2 and 0.6 can not be precisely defined in c u can't get the correct bits in c. In c the decimal points are
Calculated with minus of power of 2. Conversion from decimal to binary is below 2^-1*b1+2^-2*b2+2^-3*b3 that is how c calculate the floating point number in c.